# Porting an iOS board game to Mac, the missing parts

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am going to port a chess game from iPad to the Mac desktop. AFAIK, the Mac SDK does not come with UIKit. I'd like to know whether the following features are available in the Mac SDK? If no, what the alternatives?

- UIViewController
- UIView block-based animations
- UIImageView
- UIGestureRecognizers
- NSTimer
- NSOperationQueue

Is [chameleon](http://chameleonproject.org/) an option?

Comment: from my current experience with Chameleon, it works as long as you are familiar with its authors design, and it seems to me this chess game is a lot simple then my own, so definitely worth giving it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTimer`, `NSOperationQueue`, and almost all other APIs in the Foundation framework are available on both iOS and Mac OS X.

`NSImageView` serves the same general purpose as `UIImageView` and has similar API.

Animation APIs are a little bit different on the Mac; see Apple's [Animation Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/Animation_Overview/Introduction/Introduction.html) for details.

There's no direct equivalent to `UIGestureRecognizer` on the Mac; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805428/) for a start on implementing equivalent functionality.

The controller logic you might put in a `UIViewController` subclass might go in any number of places in a Mac app, depending on what kind of app you're making and how you want its interface to work. Apple's [Mac App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543) is a good place to get started on how the Cocoa app/window/view architecture works.

I'd be a bit leery of Chameleon: for one thing, [its GitHub](https://github.com/BigZaphod/Chameleon) hasn't seen activity in some time.